# SilverLight: Getting XML injection issue while doing Fortify scan C#

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, fortify

Actually getting database data from example1.svc file, and the code in MainPage.xaml.cs file is here

```
namespace project1
    {
     public partial class MainPage : UserControl
      {
        XDocument yeardoc=null;
        void objSrcYearCompleted(object sender, 
                                 YearCompltedEventArgs e)
        {
               yeardoc= XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        }
      }
    }
```

when it is scanned through fortify, getting XML injection at the line of

```
 yeardoc= XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
```

i was struggling about this issue from last one day. How can i avoid XML injection by changing of above code. it helps lot if anybody has given suggestion regarding this fortify issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Read following article : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_XML_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-008)

Comment: I have same issue with wcf rial services in c# silverlight visual studio project. with zap this is possible to change parameters in request and resend it and getting a response with exception about bat xml formatting. I wondered how we prevent from this type injection. we dont have access in process of xml making(request) then how prevent or validate before creating this exception .And really is this a xml injection in high risk level?